# Is there a way to disconnect zoom-client from the "home" interface to prevent it from accessing system files?

Tags: security, snap, zoom-meeting

I'm using the zoom-client snap. It works well, but I don't like the fact that it has the "home" interface connected, which gives it access to my files. I tried to disconnect the "home" interface, but then when I start zoom-client, all the text from the GUI is gone (does it take the font it uses from outside its container?).

Is there a way to make this snap work being disconnected from the "home" interface?

Comment: The [home](https://snapcraft.io/docs/home-interface) interface does not permit access to hidden personal files (anything prepended with a dot). So it cannot read your `.thunderbird` email nor rummage through your `.firefox` profile, nor any of your `.cache` or `.config` files, etc. The [personal files](https://snapcraft.io/docs/personal-files-interface) interface is needed for that.

Comment: disconnecting home should definitely work without trashing any fonts, would you mind opening an issue at https://github.com/ogra1/zoom-snap/issues ? we can take it on from there